Minimizing $\frac{1}{2}\|x-x_0\|^2 +\frac{1}{2}\|y-y_0\|^2$ subject to $F(x)=y, G(y)=b$
Let $x\in \mathbb{R}^m, y\in \mathbb{R}^n$, and $F:\mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n, G:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^k$ be linear operators.
I would like to find the proximal operator for the set
$\{(x,y)|F(x)=y, G(y)=b\}$
That is, for a given $x_0\in \mathbb{R}^m, y_0\in \mathbb{R}^n$, I want to find a closed-form solution for the following problem:
$\textrm{minimize}_{x,y}  \quad \frac{1}{2}\|x-x_0\|^2 +\frac{1}{2}\|y-y_0\|^2$
$\textrm{subject to} \quad F(x)=y, G(y)=b$
where $b\in \mathbb{R}^k$ is a fixed vector.
Background
This is a subproblem for a larger optimization problem, where I am solving the problem by the Douglas-Rachford algorithm. What I am solving is an extension of some known problem, and in that problem, they consider the proximal operator of what corresponds to $\{(x,y)|F(x)=y\}$. That is, I am solving a problem with more constraints.
If the constraint set is just $\{(x,y)|F(x)=y\}$, the early study had the following closed-form solution:
By substituting $y=F(x)$, we want to minimize $\frac{1}{2}\|x-x_0\|^2 +\frac{1}{2}\|F(x)-y_0\|^2$, and the first derivative in terms of $x$ gives us $ x-x_0 + F^*(F(x)-y_0)$. Here $F^*$ is the adjoint of the operator $F$. Setting the first derivative to 0 and solving for $x$ gives us $x = (\textrm{Id}+F^* F)^{-1}(x_0+F^* y_0)$, and this is the solution. $\square$
Now, I would like to find a similar formula for our extended problem, but I am stuck trying to do so.
My attempt
Similar to the above, I consider the Lagrangian after substituting $y=F(x)$:
\begin{equation} L = \frac{1}{2}\|x-x_0\|^2 +\frac{1}{2}\|F(x)-y_0\|^2 + \lambda^T (GF(x))-b)\end{equation}
Take the first derivative (or the gradient):
\begin{equation} (x-x_0) + F^*(F(x)-y_0) + (GF)^* \lambda\end{equation}
However, we need to find both $\lambda$ and $x$, which is impossible since the equation is underdetermined. I can apply $G\circ F$ on both sides, eliminating the first $x$, but I couldn't eliminate the second $x$.
Are there any better approaches?

You have $\ m\ $ equations
$$
0=x-x_0+F^*\big(Fx-y_0\big)+\big(GF\big)^*\lambda\tag{1}\label{e1}
$$
from your first-order optimality condition, and $\ k\ $ equations
$$
GFx=b\tag{2}\label{e2}
$$
that $\ x\ $ must satisfy. Altogether, therefore, you have $\ m+k\ $ equations for the $\ m+k\ $ entries of $\ x\ $ and $\ \lambda\ .$ Thus, the system will only be underdetermined if the matrix $\ GF\ $ doesn't have full rank.  In that case, however, solutions of equation \eqref{e2} exist only if $\ b\ $ lies in the column space of $\ GF\ ,$ and then the constraints are equivalent to a smaller set
$$
H(x)=b_1\tag{2'}\label{e2'}
$$
where the matrix $\ H\ $ has full rank. Unless the number of rows of $\ H\ $ is less than the number of its columns the equation \eqref{e2'} will have a unique solution for $\ x\ .$  Otherwise, the optimality condition becomes
$$
0=x-x_0+F^*\big(Fx-y_0\big)+H^*\lambda_1\tag{1'}\label{e1'}
$$
From equation \eqref{e1'}, we get
$$
x=\big(\text{Id}+F^*F\big)^{-1}\big(x_0+F^*y_0-H^*\lambda_1\big)\ ,\tag{3}\label{e3}
$$
and then, substituting for $\ x\ $ in equation \eqref{e2'},
$$
b_1=H\big(\text{Id}+F^*F\big)^{-1}\big(x_0+F^*y_0-H^*\lambda_1\big)
$$
or, equivalently,
\begin{align}
H\big(\text{Id}+F^*F\big)^{-1}H^*\lambda_1&=H\big(\text{Id}+F^*F\big)^{-1}\big(x_0+F^*y_0\big)-b_1\ .
\end{align}
Since $\ H\ $ has full rank and fewer rows than columns, the matrix $\ H\big(\text{Id}+F^*F\big)^{-1}H^*\ $ is positive definite, and therefore invertible.  Therefore,
\begin{align}
\lambda_1&=\big(H\big(\text{Id}+F^*F\big)^{-1}H^*\big)^{-1}{\big(H\big(\text{Id}+F^*F\big)^{-1}\big(x_0+F^*y_0\big)-b_1\big)}
\end{align}
and substituting this expression for $\ \lambda_1\ $ back into equation \eqref{e3} will give you a closed form expression for the optimal $\ x\ .$

Thanks. I was just looking at your calculation again, but in the second to the last line, shouldn't the right-hand side be  $H(\textrm{Id}+F^* F)^{-1}(x_0+F^* y_0) - b_1$?

Yes , the sign of the right hand sides of both of the last two equations was wrong.  Apologies for the error (which I've now fixed) and thank you for picking it up.
